# How to match a number separated by space or starting of the line

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to match numbers that are having a length between 6-14 separated by space or **:** or maybe at the start of the line. I'm using the following regex:  `/[ |:](\d[\s\-()]*){6,14}/g`

For the following lines of input it is matching like below,

```
Number1 :545-867-4845 - match +545-867-4845
Number2=5459485459855 - no match
Number3: 9526 4412 52 - match +9526 4412 52
Number4 55 55 55 - match +55 55 55
Number52017 11 - no match   
5459485459855 - no match //should match
```

Regex is failing the last Use case. What I did wrong?

Comment: There is no space or semi/colon before digits. I mean this part of your regex `[ |:]`

Comment: Use [`(?:^|[\s:])(\d(?:[\s()-]*\d){5,13})(?!\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/g4AxTV/1) and get Group 1.

Comment: the last number is not separated by space or :, why should it match?

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47075449/3832970) for the correct solution. Code to extract multiple matches per input is provided, too.

Comment: You accepted a wrong solution. [`/(?:^|\s|:)(\d[\d\s\-()]{5,13})(?:\s|$)/`](https://regex101.com/r/uPku3C/1) matches strings like `1-------`. You wanted to match strings having 6 to 14 digits optionally separated with whitespaces, `-`, `(` or `)`.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, all I needed was ?:^  that's it. so https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47075151/how-to-match-a-number-separated-by-space-or-starting-of-the-line#answer-47075212 is the first answer I got. So I accepted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[ |:]` means "Match one space, vertical bar, or colon here." You probably meant `(?:^| |:)` which means "Match beginning of input, space, or colon here" (the `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group used to group the alternation, which is what the `|` is).

There are a couple of other changes I'd make to that, though:

```
/(?:^|\s|:)(\d[\d\s\-()]{5,13})(?:\s|$)/
```

- Start with beginning-of-input, a space, or a colon
- Require a digit
- Require 5-13 more digits, spaces, dashes, or parentheses (making a total of 6-14)
- Require a space or end-of-input
- No `g` flag

Example and Tests:

```js
var rex = /(?:^|\s|:)(\d[\d\s\-()]{5,13})(?:\s|$)/;
[
    {str: "Number1 :545-867-4845", expect: "545-867-4845"},
    {str: "Number2=5459485459855", expect: null},
    {str: "Number3: 9526 4412 52", expect: "9526 4412 52"},
    {str: "Number4 55 55 55",      expect: "55 55 55"},
    {str: "Number52017 11",        expect: null},
    {str: "5459485459855",         expect: "5459485459855"}
].forEach(test);

function test(entry) {
    var match = rex.exec(entry.str);
    match = match && match[1];
    console.log("Testing " + entry.str + ", got " + match + ", " + (match == entry.expect ? "OK" : "ERROR"));
}
```

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón: Yeah, I found further issues with the rest of the regex when adding a live example; I've updated to address them.

Comment: regex working fine, but matched special character(space or colon) is coming in the match when executed, it was there earlier, could you skip the special character.

Comment: @sitchie: Not with a single match, no. You have to match and then remove non-digits. (But please note that phone numbers **are not** numbers and removing groupings may make the number unintelligible.)

Answer (score 1):

You must add an alternative to match the start of string when matching a space or a colon in front of the expected match: `(?:^|[ :])` (or `(?:^|[\s:])` to account for any whitespace).

Also, you need to check the context on both sides to ensure you match digit sequences (with some non-digit symbols in between) of the desired length. Right now, you will match 14 digit chunks even in case there are more digits after the 14th digit, and you will also match any trailing non-digit chars you allow in between digits. To only make sure you get 6 to 14 digits, add `(?!\d)` negative lookahead that will fail the match if there is a digit immediately to the right of the current location.

I suggest re-writing it as

```
/(?:^|[\s:])(\d(?:[\s()-]*\d){5,13})(?!\d)/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/g4AxTV/1/). Get Group 1 value:

```js
var rx = /(?:^|[ :])(\d(?:[\s()-]*\d){5,13})(?!\d)/g;
var strs = ["Number1 :545-867-4845","Number2=5459485459855","Number3: 9526 4412 52","Number4 55 55 55","Number52017 11","5459485459855"];
for (var s of strs) {
  var m;
  while (m = rx.exec(s)) {
    console.log(s, "=>", m[1]);
  }
}
```